Why I am getting error in my return statement in my interceptor?
I am getting error when trying to run the code I got from the internet. I am trying to catch the 401 unauthorized error so I can generate new access token and new refresh token.
Here is the code in frontend:
import { TokenApiModel } from '../model/token.api.model';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgToastService } from 'ng-angular-popup';
import { AuthService } from '../services/authService';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpErrorResponse,
  HttpEvent
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, Observable, switchMap, throwError, finalize, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private toast: NgToastService, private router: Router) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const myToken = this.auth.getToken();
    console.log("token is ok...")

    // this.start.load();
    if(myToken){
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {Authorization: "Bearer "+ myToken}
      })
    }

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((err:any)=>{
        if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
          if(err.status === 401){
            //this.toast.warning({detail:"Warning", summary:"Token is expired, Please Login again"});
            //this.router.navigate(['login'])
            //handle
            return this.handleUnAuthorizedError(request,next);
          }
        }
        return throwError(()=> err)
      })
    );
  }

the error is with the return statement at the beginning of code. return next.handle(request).pipe and error is Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'. Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<any>'

any ideas why ?
